# URL rewrite for language localization removes default page functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string file_path = Request.RawUrl.ToLower();
        char[] separator = new char[] { '/' };

        string[] parts = file_path.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (parts.Length > 0 && parts[0] == "de")
        {

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de");

            Context.RewritePath("~/" + file_path.Substring(4), true);
        }
        else if (parts.Length > 0 && parts[0] == "en")
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");

            Context.RewritePath("~/" + file_path.Substring(4), true);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
        }

    }
```

I am using this code in my WebForms site in order to use the more SEO friendly structure of https://example.com/en/some/url

Rather than the cookie-based system I previously intended to use.

However, now that I have done this I get a 500 error if I don't use a URL that specifies the file also. For example https://example.com/en/ does not work, however /en/default does - what is the proper way to handle this so that both work?

Comment: Please post the code you are using to rewrite your URLs. I don't see how anyone can help you without seeing that code.

Comment: It is available above...

The bit that says

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: i just got idea doing the similar thing from other way around through video URL[aspnet](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-multi-lingual-site-with-localization)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Multi-Lingual Site?

[Globalization and Localization in asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-multi-lingual-site-with-localization)

Such as

1. - http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/default.aspx
2. - http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/default.aspx